# Node Js, Sequelize and Jade. How get data from has-many associations between them?

Tags: database, node.js, foreach, pug, sequelize.js

I'm working on a NodeJS+Sequelize+jade web-app. I have a table called box and another one called user. The user has a one-to-many relation with box. What I like to do is list and show in a jade-template all the box details, including the user who owns it.

First I created the tables using sequelize tools

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

      var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        name: { 
          type: DataTypes.STRING, 
          allowNull: false
        },
        email: { 
          type: DataTypes.STRING, 
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true
        },
        password: { 
          type: DataTypes.STRING, 
          allowNull: false
        },
        dateOfBirth: DataTypes.DATE,
        role: {
          type:   DataTypes.ENUM,
          values: ['ADMIN', 'USER'],
          defaultValue: 'USER'
        }



      },{ 
       classMethods:{
          associate: function(models) {
            User.hasMany(models.Box);
          }     
       })

      return User;
      };
```

The same to box:

```
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

          var Box = sequelize.define('Box',{

            boxTitle: {
                    type : DataTypes.STRING,
                    allowNull: false

            },
            lifetime: {
                    type : DataTypes.DATE,
                    allowNull : false
            },
            status: {
                    type:   DataTypes.ENUM,
                    values: ['ACTIVE', 'NOTACTIVE'],
                    defaultValue: 'ACTIVE'
            },
            count: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull : false
            }
          },{
              classMethods:{
                associate: function(models) {
                  Box.belongsTo(models.User);

               }   
          });


          return Box;

        };
```

So, when I put some data in the database, I'm trying to print te box information:

```
  each box in boxes
    each user in box.users

      tr      
        td= box.getDataValue('boxTitle')
        td= user.getDataValue('name')
        td= box.getDataValue('lifetime')
        td= box.getDataValue('count')
        td= box.getDataValue('status')
```

I did this so far, but I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I believe the program is not recognizing the association between those two tables, but I'm not sure.
Does anyone knows how can I solve this problem, or maybe to it in a different way?
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: It would be good to see your JavaScript code too. `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` could be coming from a for loop jade is creating to render `each box in boxes` but `boxes` is undefined so it can't get its `length`. Just a hunch...

Comment: Done! thanks fot the tip.

Comment: Without seeing the code used in the router this Question can't be solved and should be closed/deleted.